# Error closing out for loop using Flask/Jinja

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am using Flask to connect a website to a database in SQLite3. Trying to iterate through table results, I am using the following code, which is based on the Flaskr tutorial (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/tutorial/templates/):

```
`{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
<ul class="students">
  {% for student in students %}
  <li>{{ student.ID }},{{ student.lastName }},{{ student.firstName }}</li>
  {% else %}
    <li> No students yet</li>
    {% endfor % }
  </ul>`
```

but I get an error that says:

`File "C:\sam\IS13\templates\show_tests.html", line 8, in template
{% endfor % }
TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of statement block', got '%'`

Is this not the proper way to close out a for loop in this setting?

Comment: you are right. I take it back!  That is a fine for look with the default clause!  I'm not sure what version of jinja that was introduced in.

Comment: Word to the wise: when you get a syntax error, look at line that's causing the error, what the compiler expected, and what it got instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closing control should be `{% endfor %}`, without a space between `%` and `}`.